# How to resolve merging conflicts on github

Tags: git, github

I have merging conflicts. I didn't want to correct it on Github because before I merge it I want to test if it is correct or not. so I downloaded the code and merged the master branch to the feature branch, then I pushed the feature branch to the remote repo. this way there is no merging conflicts. Is my approach correct? what other ways do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally the best practice: merge conflicts should be resolved locally, as you did, because you can then compile and test, before pushing back the result.

An alternative would be, for simple conflicts, to resolve on GitHub, but then to have [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) to build and run tests.
For example: [github-action-tester](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-tester).